# How to use Bash to create a folder if it doesn't already exist?

Tags: bash, directory

```
#!/bin/bash
if [!-d /home/mlzboy/b2c2/shared/db]; then
    mkdir -p /home/mlzboy/b2c2/shared/db;
fi;
```

This doesn't seem to work.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Why do you have semicolons?

Comment: The `;` token is a command separator, so is newline. As `then` is a separate command, the preceding semicolon is needed to be be able to write it in the same line. The semicolons after `mkdir` and `fi` are superflous.

Answer (score 399):

First, in Bash `[` is just a command, which expects string `]` as a last argument, so the whitespace before the closing bracket (as well as between `!` and `-d` which need to be two separate arguments too) is **important**:

```
if [ ! -d /home/mlzboy/b2c2/shared/db ]; then
  mkdir -p /home/mlzboy/b2c2/shared/db;
fi
```

Second, since you are using `-p` switch for `mkdir`, this check is useless, because this is what it [does](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mkdir) in the first place. Just write:

```
mkdir -p /home/mlzboy/b2c2/shared/db;
```

and that's it.

Comment: Note: the `-p` flag causes any parent directories to be created if necessary.

Comment: My god, I've never knew that "[" is a command. This explains so many of my problems... Easily the most useful thing I've ever read on StackOverflow.

Comment: Wow! Knowing that "[" is a command in bash is such an eye-opener. I feel like a lot of issues with my bash scripts are now resolved!

Comment: Incredible to find out that "[" is a command. That's made a lot of things click for me that didn't make sense before. Thank you!

Comment: How to check using Regex to identify the folder? Ex: if [ ! -d /home/mlzboy/b2*/shared/db ];

Comment: @mlzboy I've seen plenty of SO questions for which none of the answers warranted being accepted as the correct answer. This is not such a case. 

Comment: [ is a  special characters (meta-characters) used for defining regular expressions https://berkeley-scf.github.io/tutorial-using-bash/regex.html

Answer (score 128):

There is actually no need to check whether it exists or not. Since you already wants to create it if it exists , just mkdir will do

```
mkdir -p /home/mlzboy/b2c2/shared/db
```

Comment: Note: the `-p` flag causes any parent directories to be created if necessary.

Answer (score 96):

Simply do:

```
mkdir /path/to/your/potentially/existing/folder
```

mkdir will throw an error if the folder already exists. To ignore the errors write:

```
mkdir -p /path/to/your/potentially/existing/folder
```

No need to do any checking or anything like that.

---

For reference:

`-p, --parents  no error if existing, make parent directories as needed` http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mkdir.1.html

Comment: The argument `-p` doesn't exactly ignore errors: it invokes a different mode where any path components that don't exist are created (and hence it is not an error if happens that zero need to be created). The behavior is different since it will create components other than the last one, which may or not be desirable.

Answer (score 29):

You need spaces inside the `[` and `]` brackets:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -d /home/mlzboy/b2c2/shared/db ] 
then
    mkdir -p /home/mlzboy/b2c2/shared/db
fi
```

Answer (score 20):

Cleaner way, exploit shortcut evaluation of shell logical operators. Right side of the operator is executed only if left side is true.

```
[ ! -d /home/mlzboy/b2c2/shared/db ] && mkdir -p /home/mlzboy/b2c2/shared/db
```

Comment: mmh, not cleaner: just shorter.
It's difficult to understand the meaning of such a statement if you come across it.

Comment: I like this, although the `-p` argument makes the check unnecessary. You can still use it when you don't want to use `-p`, that is when you *don't want* all the parent directories to be created automatically.

Comment: Actually it's even shorter to write `[ -d /path/to/dir ] || mkdir /path/to/dir` .. right side is executed when the left side is false.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should re-format your code a bit:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -d /home/mlzboy/b2c2/shared/db ]; then
    mkdir -p /home/mlzboy/b2c2/shared/db;
fi;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your directory wherever

OUTPUT_DIR=whatever

```
if [ ! -d ${OUTPUT_DIR} ]
then
    mkdir -p ${OUTPUT_DIR}
fi
```