# Basic Shell Scripting in BASH

Tags: linux, bash

I'm in my first semester of BASH Scripting and I am having some difficulty. I've taken other programming courses like C++ or Java but the syntax of Bash is killing me. I'd love some advice on this problem. I need to do the following:

- Extract Today's data from /var/log/secure file
- Check to see if I have a directory called 'mylogs'
- If I don't - then create one
- Check to see if you already have a file matching the current day, month and hour
  in the ‘mylogs’ directory.
- If you do, echo to the screen “File exists, nothing written to my log”, and
  exit. If it doesn’t exist then write today’s data from /var/log/secure to your
  ‘mylog-month-day-hour’ file. Example (February, 4th at 2pm) output:
  mylog-02-04-14

I just need help with the syntax portion of the script.

Thanks - I'd love any websites helping out in BASH as well.

Comment: I recommend you narrow your question down to something with a definitive answer.

Comment: this really sounds like an assignment list for your class. http://whatHaveYouTried.com ? Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Extract Today's data from /var/log/secure file

You could do this ...

```
grep "^Feb 24" /var/log/secure
```

- Check to see if I have a directory called 'mylogs' and If I don't - then create one

You can do this ...

```
test -d mylogs || mkdir mylogs
```

- Check to see if you already have a file matching the current day, month and hour in the ‘mylogs’ directory. (Assuming file names are of the format DDMMHH)

  test -e mylogs/`date +%d%m%H` && echo "I already have a file"
- If you do, echo to the screen “File exists, nothing written to my log”, and exit. If it doesn’t exist then write today’s data from /var/log/secure to your ‘mylog-month-day-hour’ file. Example (February, 4th at 2pm) output: mylog-02-04-14

Eh you should get the idea by now.  You can tackle this one now I think ;)  A helpful command to know is `man -k <keyword>`

Comment: Thanks - my only question is (I've been researching this) is that I need it be run everyday - so running Grep Feb 24 wouldn't work - so is there a variable for just date?

Comment: For dates with single-digit day-of-month values, `grep "^Feb 2"` will match 2nd, and 20th-29th... could use e.g. "^Feb 2[^0-9]", or if you knew it was followed by a particular character, look for that e.g. "^Feb 2," or "^Feb 2 ".

Answer (score 1):

First read some bash basics. Then, there are links describing your particular problem.

- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-howto-unzip-files-in-root-directory/
- [Check if a directory exists in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-shell-script)
- [How to use Bash to create a folder if it doesn't already exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906579/how-to-use-bash-to-create-a-folder-if-it-doesnt-already-exist)
- http://www.electrictoolbox.com/test-file-exists-bash-shell/
- http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-write-to-syslog.html

Comment: Thanks - and if I wanted to grab the date from /var/log/secure - would I use grep?

Comment: Yep, it's good searching tool. When my server was hacked I was sniffing for details with grep.

Comment: grep, sed, awk, cut, find, date, tr, test operators, `>`, `<`, `|` (I am probably leave a few out) are all commands you need to read the manpages for if you want to be proficient in write shell script.