# Command is_dir not found

Tags: bash

I'm trying to check if a folder exists. If it doesn't, I create it.

I have this code:

```
if [ $(is_dir "$contaniningdir/run") = "NO"]; then
  mkdir "$containingdir/run"
fi
```

However, I'm getting:

`is_dir: command not found`

So how what's the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
if [ ! -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
  # your mkdir and other stuff ... 
fi
```

as per [this question/answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-shell-script). Another relevant question/answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906579/how-to-use-bash-to-create-a-folder-if-it-doesnt-already-exist).

One of the comments also mentions an important notice:

> One thing to keep in mind: [ ! -d "$DIRECTORY" ] will be true either
>   if $DIRECTORY doesn't exist, or if does exist but isn't a directory.

For more you should probably check that other question's page.

[is_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) is a PHP function that you probably mixed with bash unintentionally :)

Answer (score 1):

bash is capable of checking for the existence of a directory without external commands:

```
if [ ! -d "${containingdir}/run" ]; then
  mkdir "${containingdir}/run"
fi
```

`!` is negation, `-d` checks if the argument exists and is a directory